# Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote

Tags: discussion, votes

I don't have to link to any particular posting.  Just check the main page.  Posts are not receiving enough votes.  Responses are not receiving enough votes.  We need to vote.

Even if you aren't contributing relevant and useful information to the community, a vote goes a long way in encouraging people to contribute!  The amount of views and votes are not correlating at a reasonable level.

Please, for the love of god, vote.  Voting, is indeed, a *significant* contribution.

(If you want to upvote this, I'd rather you go upvote an actual question/response)

Comment: We would be remiss if we didn't provide a link to the world-famous ["Vote early and often!"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often) post!

Comment: (but yes, 100% this!)

Comment: TeX community is best community.  We could learn a lesson or two from them.

Comment: It goes without saying, but I'll mention it anyway, that both up and down votes should still be given based on merit.

Comment: Leadership by example works for me ;)

Comment: I'm going out on a full-on voting spree...

Comment: Who's saying no ones voting? I get a lot of votes, only problem is most of them are votes to close the question

Comment: May be it's too much hardwork sometimes to determine whether to vote.