# Thanks for being more diligent about homework questions!

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, homework

By and large, our resident scholars-in-training have been doing a commendable job with including their initial attempts in the homework problems that have been posted.  I'm pleased that new users to the site have been following the good example of those "askers" that have been around for a while.

If any sub-par questions sneak through, please prompt the user with a short, polite comment to include their initial impressions, educated guesses, etc. and follow up with a vote to close or a flag (for users with reputation < 500) if the question is not improved after a reasonable amount of time.  Questions can always be reopened after editing, and we're not in the business of rapidly deleting anything but the most egregious of off-topic questions, so there is ample time for this.

So, once again, keep up the good work!  Additionally, consider giving quality questions or answers an [upvote](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/vote-vote-vote-vote-vote-vote-vote) if you run across them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone continues to do a great job with this, so keep it up!  Even though we are slated to graduate and have crossed that hurdle, your efforts are even more valuable to keep the site running smoothly in the years to come.