# Contributing badges by up-voting. Is it a good idea?

Tags: discussion

For some time, I have been stumbling across some questions/answers that has 9 or 24 upvotes. So, I thought that I should upvote the question or answer  so that they get the "nice question" or "nice answer" badge.

Some unlucky users  asks  or answers a good question or answer but eventually gets 9/24 upvotes. They deserve a badges. Some users are like:-

> One more!!!!!  Just one more!!!!!!

But the "one more" never comes.... They have been waiting for that "one more" and expecting they will get a badges. But they never get it because he is one upvote short.........

There are also some users like this:-

> Who cares... I got my question question answered/ I have answered a question............

But still... contributing badges by upvoting seems to be a noble act. There is no waste of time. Just a click.... Is this a good idea?

**Condition applied**:  Please don't get over-excited and start hunting such type of question/answers and blindly upvote. If you unexpectedly stumble upon or eventually come across such question and feel like upvoting, upvote those......

Comment: I don't understand what the question is? If an answer/question is good then upvote it. Otherwise don't.

Comment: Well . . . we are usually just joking in "The Periodic Table", if that's part of what caused you to do this. I think I can safely tell you that **none** of the regular members and avid answerers of this site are here right now because of a couple of imaginary digital internet numbers going up. Rep and badges are incentives, and rewards are not ends, but means.

Comment: @IͶΔ \*coughs\* Erm … ^^' Well … ^^''' … Thanks for the trust, but … ^^'' …

Comment: @Jan ಠ_ಠ­­­­­­­

Comment: @Jan, What is it you are talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I absolutely second bon's comment.

**A vote shall be given only judging the quality of the post itself.
 Upvote a question or answer when it deserves it.** (It often does.) Stockpiling (just adding a vote to the question, because there are already a lot of votes) votes is not a good idea.

That being said, I think we have a far more serious problem. The community can only really function if we actually vote. The less impact a single vote has, the better the inner workings of the site.
The overall voting on this site could be improved. While the community of active users grows, the (total) voting goes down. Don't be too shy to give encouragement. **Vote early, vote often.** I am also including downvotes here, I think the overall number of votes is just too low. It improved during winterbash (is this good?), because people were hunting for hats.

I personally am a lazy voter, and I often read a question and forget to vote and later find out that I missed it. If I am in third place in the [statistics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) then there must be something off.

Related:

## [Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/341/4945)!