# Voting at chemistry.se is less

Tags: discussion, voting

Why there is not as much as voting to questions and answers as in other stack exchange sites like overflow or information security?
Why users do not cast their votes even its simple?

Comment: I'd like to see how you reached this conclusion.

Comment: @IͶΔ.             See this it has 4K upvotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: $\ldots$ and 371751 views. $$\frac{4149}{371751} = 0.0111$$ [This question on our site](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden) has 120 votes and 12391 views. $$\frac{120}{12391} =0.0096$$ Contrast this to the fact that more votes make a bigger difference in the ratio than views, and the question on Chemistry is 3 years younger than SO's question. Let's also take into account the number of eligible voters since those questions were posted. Does your argument still hold?

Comment: @IͶΔ           So you want to say that I should have asked why the voting per view(density or concentration or per user) is more on chemistry.se?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have asked anything when there's no issue. Anyway, if there's to be a good outcome out of this, it's that people start voting more,  esp. [OP](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/23944/jm97?tab=topactivity).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack Overflow has 5.4 million users, Information security has 81000 users. Chemistry has a meagre 16000. [These are just the plain registered users numbers.](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users)

From the site analytics I know that there are about 100 users (average) that take action every day. There are about 1000 votes cast every week.

We are a small community, and yes, voting could be more. But it is completely normal behaviour for the site. There is nothing to worry about. Additionally, voting has been increasing (in average) for the past two (or three) years now (with an anomaly around the graduation of the site). The trend is upwards, that is good.

But just in case you did not know already: [Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote Vote](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/341/4945)!

Comment: I'm confident [this user](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/7448/i%cd%b6%ce%94) is the only anomaly in voting here.

Comment: @IͶΔ http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all

Comment: @Loong that user is old-timerer, doesn't count. :P